# How could i revert changes to a guild | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am making a discord bot that when you change the server, it'll update it back. Currently, i have this

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_update(before, after):
    guild.before
```

Ive looked in all the docs and I cannot find how i can reverse all these changes. Any ideas on how i can accomplish this?

Comment: Look at [`Guild.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.edit) to see how you would change it back.  One problem you could have is that when your bot edits it back, that will create a new `on_guild_update` event, and so on.  Have you considered restricting the manage guild permission using roles?